# .catch(error=>{}) is not showing my error when i response it. But when I console it it shows the error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on an API and I am getting some problems for my errors. When I responded to it it shows me an empty array in postman but in logger it shows me the error. This is my code.
Cluster1 and Cluster2 are two collection which I am making  collection to them. So in the Code I am trying that if the id found in cluster1 (which is products collection), then post your order in cluster2 then (return promise on save) but I own purpose created the error which i commented below so to check that either both `.catch()` callback functions working or not.

[image]

```
app.post('/orders',(req,res,next)=>{
const id=req.body.id;
console.log(id);
Cluster1.findById(id,()=>{
    order = new Cluster2 ({
        productId:id,
        quantity:req.body.quantity,
        pName:req.body.pName,
        });
    order.save().then(order=>{
        res.json({
            message:"Your order has been Posted",
            YourPostedOrderIs:order.pName,
            YourQuantityis:order.quantity,
            YouPriceis:(pPrice*quantity),//I on purpose make this error to check the error when this 
id is fin in cluster1
            YourRequestIs:{type:"Post",url:"http://localhost:1111/"+order.productId}
        })
        })
//This Catch call back function give me empty error in postman when I response it.
    .catch(error=>{
        res.json(error);
        console.log(error);
    })
    })
.catch(error=>{
    res.json("Out Of Stock You cant Place the Order");
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `res.json(error);` try the following:

```
res.status(500).json({
    message: error.message || "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brother for helping me it works

Comment: Brother Anuj I am at early junior level mean stack developer. How can I learn and become good so I can make professional applications

Comment: And brother before reading your answer I always do res.json(error) and it gives me error all the time. Why in this api  i have to use error.message to get the error

Comment: My observation is that in the Express docs for response.json, it stringifies the JSON before sending: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json
However, error instances, since they are instances of the Error class, typically do not return anything meaningful when stringified. So, it is always a good practice to deconstuct whatever properties you want from an error if you with to see them in API response.

Comment: And about becoming a better developer, just use every learning resource at your disposal and keep making good projects. You will learn more not with tutorials but by making new things and in this profession, you will NEVER stop learning.

Comment: Great Thanks you very much Sir can I have you email or hangouts or whats app I want to stay in contact with you

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the res.json like so:

```
return res.json(500, {
                    error,
                    message: "some error"
                 });
```

Comment: Thank you brother